# Is there any possibility to do the click event with css?

Tags: css, click

I would like to display apple in green color (bg color) instead of mango in red colour (bg color) on **`click`** on the mango, I know it's possible with **`hover`** or using **`javascript`**. Is there any way to do it with **css**  on **mouse click**?

```css
#two
    {
        display:none;
    }
    #one
    {
      background-color :red;
    }
```

```html
 <html>
      <head>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="hov.css">
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="one">
          <p>mango</p>
        </div>
        <div id="two">
          <p>apple</p>
        </div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

which is best to use **`js`** for the click purpose.

### CSS Only Solution

here is a **simple hack to create the click functionality  using css**
for this purpose.here is a simple hack using `checkbox` and `label`.

```css
label {
    display: block;
    background: red;
}
label:after{
content: "Mango";  
}

#demo:checked + label {
    background: Green;
    color: white;
}
#demo:checked + label:after{
  content: "Apple";
  }
.hide{
  display:none;
  }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="demo" class="hide"/>
<label for="demo"></label>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't do what you want with only CSS, but you can use the **:active** selector to change it while clicking on it.

See that: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by "click" and "display".

If you mean can you toggle the appearance of the "apple" div by *just* clicking the "mango" div, then NO...you need javascript.

However, if you just want to see the "mango" div while the mouse button is clicked **and held down**, then the pseudo-class `:active` is what you require...in conjuction with a suitable sibling selector.

```css
#two {
  display: none;
  background: green;
}
#one {
  background-color: red;
}
#one:active + #two {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="one">
  <p>mango [click and hold]</p>
</div>
<div id="two">
  <p>apple</p>
</div>
```

**Note: This selector *only* works on siblings...it will not work on the `p` tag to affect the "apple" div.**